# Is there a way to change react Router on store change?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm learning react by creating a todo list. the lists are organized by projects. So I have an object with an `projects` array and a `lists` object.
    {
        projects: store.projects,
        lists: store.lists
    }

The lists would look something like this `{projectName: ['list1',...]}`

My routes are whatever I have in the `projects` array

```
const routes = ({
  var children = this.props.projects;
    const routes = {
        path: '/',
        component: Nav,
        indexRoute: { component: Layout },
        childRoutes: [ ]
    }
    for(let i in children){
      routes.childRoutes.push({path: children[i], component: Layout})
    }
    return routes
})
class Routing extends React.Component{
  render(){
    return(<Router className="row" routes={routes}   history={browserHistory} />)
  }
}
```

So far so good. Now if I dispatch an action which pushes an item into my `projects` I get this error message:

> Warning: [react-router] You cannot change ; it will be ignored

Is there a way for the router to be recreated every time I add some item to `this.props.projects`

Comment: The way you have implemented this is wrong, @gravityplanx answer below is the right* way to proceed forward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't want to create individual routes for each product.  What you want is a single route that has a variable in it's path:

```
<Route path="projects/:name" component={Layout} />
```

Entering this route will give you access to the `name` value, via `this.props.params.name`.